# How to mute sound from one VM on a host only?

Tags: windows-10, audio, virtual-machine, vmware, teamviewer

I am using VMWare Workstation 15 on a Windows 10 host. I let my friend use one of the VMs in it, running Windows 10 as well, to connect to it remotely. The issue is that I hear every sound on the host what's going on in that specific VM.

So I'm wondering, can I mute that specific VM on the host only and but let the person connecting to that VM keep the sound on?

Comment: You set it from the client.

Comment: @Tetsujin set it how? If I mute it from the client, the person connecting to that client won't be able to hear the sounds. But that's not what I want.

Comment: The client is the person connecting ;) Yours is the host.

Comment: Sorry was working from my phone earlier - answer now provided.

Comment: @Tetsujin nah, it's all good. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disconnect the VM's sound device.  You can do this in a few ways:

- VM > Settings > Hardware > Sound Card > Device status, uncheck Connected.
- VM > Removable Devices > Sound Card > Disconnect
- Right-click on the sound icon in the status bar and choose Disconnect.

Disconnecting the VM's sound device shouldn't affect the guest.

Another option would be to open the Volume Mixer on your host and to mute "VMware Workstation VMX", although doing so would mute all VMs.

Comment: Will that still send audio to the remote user?

Comment: @Tetsujin As I said, it shouldn't affect the guest, so it shouldn't affect remote users that connect directly to the guest.

Comment: @Tetsujin I haven't tried it. But my guess is that it will not work, because the remote assistance software (TeamViewer in my case) will not see any sound device on the system.

I was able to sort-of resolve it though by switching the sound card for the VM to the on-board one (on the motherboard) that I wasn't using. But that wouldn't be ideal if I had only one sound card. With more than one, I can go to VM -> Settings -> Sound Card and pick "Specify host sound card" from the drop-down list - or use the one that's not used.

Comment: @c00000fd You should try it.  As I've said twice already, it should not affect the guest.  Disconnecting the sound device disconnects it from the host; it does not remove the sound device from the guest's virtual hardware.

Comment: @jamesdlin it did work. I apologize for making my assumptions. And thank you for posting your help. Somehow I thought that disabling it will remove the sound card from the guest (like it would do with a network adapter, for instance.) So I learned something today. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I only have the Mac version of MS RDC for the screenshot, but you do this on the client, not the host.

You set the audio prefs to "On this computer". This leaves it silent on the host & plays on the remote client.

[image]

Comment: Oh, that's really cool. I was using Team Viewer. IDK if MSFT Remote Desktop can work without exposing a public IP for that VM? Also do you know if TeamViewer supports such feature as well?

Comment: I haven't used TeamViewer in a decade, sorry. I know it can be done over *'teh interwebz'* but it's not something i'm practised at. All my remotes are in the building, so I don't have intrusion worries. I like the irony that I manage a network of PCs from my Mac;)) [& a network of Macs too]

Comment: Yeah, that's kinda funny. I didn't even know that MSFT had their Remote Desktop app for a Mac.

Comment: For a very long time, same as Office. They do it for iOS & Android too

Comment: You can do it on the host.  The host just needs to disconnect itself from the VM's sound device.